# Unity3d 2019.3.0f1 with Xcode 10.1 - Got Build time error - clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, frameworks, vuforia

ld: warning: arm64 function not 4-byte aligned: _unwind_tester from /Users/apple/Desktop/Work/Viewa/JCH Repo/VIEWA IOS 2019/Build/ViewaStaging/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(unwind_test_arm64.o)
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_GoogleSignIn_GetUserId", referenced from:
      _GoogleSignInImpl_GoogleSignIn_GetUserId_m6FE093B67B543C328DEEB271EEF3F96DA22828E4 in Assembly-CSharp2.o
      _U3CU3Ec__DisplayClass5_0_U3Cget_ResultU3Eb__7_mF938FF23198EBBFEE319EE9141D250244E3290F1 in Assembly-CSharp2.o
     (maybe you meant: _GoogleSignInImpl_GoogleSignIn_GetUserId_m6FE093B67B543C328DEEB271EEF3F96DA22828E4)
  "_GoogleSignIn_GetIdToken", referenced from:
      _GoogleSignInImpl_GoogleSignIn_GetIdToken_mFB400A76685D3B20EE65EA952976256F62FF485D in Assembly-CSharp2.o
      _U3CU3Ec__DisplayClass5_0_U3Cget_ResultU3Eb__4_m2D1F12F36915775B390626DEDE250D154B49065B in Assembly-CSharp2.o
     (maybe you meant: _GoogleSignInImpl_GoogleSignIn_GetIdToken_mFB400A76685D3B20EE65EA952976256F62FF485D)
  "_GoogleSignIn_GetFamilyName", referenced from:
      _GoogleSignInImpl_GoogleSignIn_GetFamilyName_m511D6C1D8713C2B6970CE4D0100E683971E03B54 in Assembly-CSharp2.o
      _U3CU3Ec__DisplayClass5_0_U3Cget_ResultU3Eb__2_m212CD5CAD0570CB48E89390A3E8123C872D11EC0 in Assembly-CSharp2.o
     (maybe you meant: _GoogleSignInImpl_GoogleSignIn_GetFamilyName_m511D6C1D8713C2B6970CE4D0100E683971E03B54)
  "_GoogleSignIn_GetDisplayName", referenced from:
      _GoogleSignInImpl_GoogleSignIn_GetDisplayName_mE63D837DE58EB21F693EC61E8EA7C5D5B079C9B3 in Assembly-CSharp2.o
      _U3CU3Ec__DisplayClass5_0_U3Cget_ResultU3Eb__0_m2F518D7B2CC928F33BD5EB76A902D70A3E06E890 in Assembly-CSharp2.o
     (maybe you meant: _GoogleSignInImpl_GoogleSignIn_GetDisplayName_mE63D837DE58EB21F693EC61E8EA7C5D5B079C9B3)
  "_GoogleSignIn_Status", referenced from:
      _GoogleSignInImpl_GoogleSignIn_Status_m304BE4B644699B321A7145A2E56E71D6639CAED9 in Assembly-CSharp2.o
      _NativeFuture_get_Status_mFA63F195C56C75AAF5C62B63B60A171E20910B67 in Assembly-CSharp2.o
     (maybe you meant: _GoogleSignInImpl_GoogleSignIn_Status_m304BE4B644699B321A7145A2E56E71D6639CAED9)
  "_GoogleSignIn_Pending", referenced from:
      _GoogleSignInImpl_GoogleSignIn_Pending_mFA7E93B590CA195B4752CDA2F010CD34CFABE130 in Assembly-CSharp2.o
      _NativeFuture_get_Pending_mAB4F57A573DA7DCD8F6EDD686BA810C615B75A8D in Assembly-CSharp2.o
     (maybe you meant: _GoogleSignInImpl_GoogleSignIn_Pending_mFA7E93B590CA195B4752CDA2F010CD34CFABE130)
  "_webviewSetScalesPageToFit", referenced from:
      _WebViewNativeIOS_webviewSetScalesPageToFit_mC3BEA61B8DCADAEAC79410CAB317D1B3DC8CA40E in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _WebViewNativeIOS_SetScalesPageToFit_m8E02EE0BBD4589800FB437341584B2EE280C1E38 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _WebViewNativeIOS_webviewSetScalesPageToFit_mC3BEA61B8DCADAEAC79410CAB317D1B3DC8CA40E)
  "_loadAchievementDescriptions", referenced from:
      _GameServicesIOS_loadAchievementDescriptions_m3BB95FD5BEF2695EEFA8BAA6D1E1A1D7B2B36CB1 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
      _GameServicesIOS_LoadAchievementDescriptions_mF6B7346D1C7FDE26B3AF1B9298240518074CDFDD in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
     (maybe you meant: _GameServicesIOS_loadAchievementDescriptions_m3BB95FD5BEF2695EEFA8BAA6D1E1A1D7B2B36CB1)
  "_GoogleSignIn_Signout", referenced from:
      _GoogleSignInImpl_SignOut_m46B3C5C6F4A220E2458C05F9B18229D0426B120A in Assembly-CSharp2.o
      _GoogleSignInImpl_GoogleSignIn_Signout_m35734A53BDF7AC7C7414E89587A78B0669AF78F1 in Assembly-CSharp2.o
     (maybe you meant: _GoogleSignInImpl_GoogleSignIn_Signout_m35734A53BDF7AC7C7414E89587A78B0669AF78F1)
  "_isAuthenticated", referenced from:
      _iOSLocalUser_get_IsAuthenticated_mD8D9DF41B4F09586F7F45F526F2CDD58F149CBB3 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _iOSLocalUser_isAuthenticated_mD85139DF26757E15425FF8EA96E907C145A6BD5B in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _iOSLocalUser_isAuthenticated_mD85139DF26757E15425FF8EA96E907C145A6BD5B)
  "_utilityBundleIdentifier", referenced from:
      _Utility_GetBundleIdentifier_mEEB030DACE6DDB83AB1E26B2DA01AEE54D2E7EC6 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass3.o
      _PlayerSettings_GetBundleIdentifier_m4D6775DB9DA5FB4813B57589DBDEDB172178210A in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass3.o
      _NativeBinding_utilityBundleIdentifier_mCEB6780C51CBB0C831137AFA990236EC9EFAD498 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass3.o
      _NativeBinding_GetBundleIdentifier_m07B75F7A0C2E820139AE9BBB0F92B7A1D3AA4680 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass3.o
     (maybe you meant: _NativeBinding_utilityBundleIdentifier_mCEB6780C51CBB0C831137AFA990236EC9EFAD498)
  "_showLoginPromptDialog", referenced from:
      _UIIOS_showLoginPromptDialog_mDE53B340403AB3EF5BD27B62B9DD2974F66A5073 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass3.o
     (maybe you meant: _UIIOS_showLoginPromptDialog_mDE53B340403AB3EF5BD27B62B9DD2974F66A5073)
  "_socialShare", referenced from:
      _SharingIOS_socialShare_mE568DDD8650E5ACA5BCDAF446D07EE046FF7EC0C in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _SharingIOS_socialShare_mE568DDD8650E5ACA5BCDAF446D07EE046FF7EC0C)
  "_showSingleFieldPromptDialog", referenced from:
      _UIIOS_showSingleFieldPromptDialog_m6F5202255F3B12C98E1F0ED0E2E1F156D3C64E7C in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass3.o
     (maybe you meant: _UIIOS_showSingleFieldPromptDialog_m6F5202255F3B12C98E1F0ED0E2E1F156D3C64E7C)
  "_shareImageOnWhatsApp", referenced from:
      _SharingIOS_shareImageOnWhatsApp_mE011579CA7273B8251D9933D164AB1A79EA97D8F in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _SharingIOS_ShowWhatsAppShareComposer_mB28E83CC9B377B6D1A78FC3E1C4EB211414DF954 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _SharingIOS_ShareImageOnWhatsApp_mF9C175947974B239D0368D0232BD763C21F5676C in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _SharingIOS_shareImageOnWhatsApp_mE011579CA7273B8251D9933D164AB1A79EA97D8F)
  "_cancelLocalNotification", referenced from:
      _NotificationServiceIOS_cancelLocalNotification_m22F318DC51CA345DF0BAB95CCB5A898D7ABEBB24 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
      _NotificationServiceIOS_CancelLocalNotification_m4F02B7AE1EC870A5F1C11DA70296886510AB51A5 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
     (maybe you meant: _NotificationServiceIOS_cancelLocalNotification_m22F318DC51CA345DF0BAB95CCB5A898D7ABEBB24)
  "_showAlertDialog", referenced from:
      _UIIOS_showAlertDialog_m61F481333C51C6B1EAE3F329186394DCBEF4A5CA in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass3.o
     (maybe you meant: _UIIOS_showAlertDialog_m61F481333C51C6B1EAE3F329186394DCBEF4A5CA)
  "_GoogleSignIn_Create", referenced from:
      _GoogleSignInImpl__ctor_m56DD97E3FEB329A7D239CDE307FF8051B1EC6FD9 in Assembly-CSharp2.o
      _GoogleSignInImpl_GoogleSignIn_Create_mECEB63F232189C615C923DA499312A2B175FCDCC in Assembly-CSharp2.o
     (maybe you meant: _GoogleSignInImpl_GoogleSignIn_Create_mECEB63F232189C615C923DA499312A2B175FCDCC)
  "_initNotificationService", referenced from:
      _NotificationServiceIOS_initNotificationService_m97600A00C46997161201B6BD3AC9102AB2C5DA23 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
     (maybe you meant: _NotificationServiceIOS_initNotificationService_m97600A00C46997161201B6BD3AC9102AB2C5DA23)
  "_share", referenced from:
      _SharingIOS_share_mD5C0B1770361E9BF9A15E53FE83492A1CC592F54 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _mbedtls_ecdh_compute_shared, __Z51Register_UnityEngine_Rigidbody2D_set_sharedMaterialv , __Z48Register_UnityEngine_MeshCollider_set_sharedMeshv , __Z48Register_UnityEngine_MeshCollider_get_sharedMeshv , __Z48Register_UnityEngine_Collider_set_sharedMaterialv , __Z55Register_UnityEngine_SkinnedMeshRenderer_get_sharedMeshv , __Z46Register_UnityEngine_MeshFilter_set_sharedMeshv , _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBSDKShareVideoContent._shareUUID , _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent._shareUUID , _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBSDKShareMessengerGenericTemplateContent._shareUUID , _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBSDKShareMediaContent._shareUUID , _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBSDKSharePhotoContent._shareUUID , _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBSDKShareMessengerMediaTemplateContent._shareUUID , _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBSDKShareCameraEffectContent._shareUUID , _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBSDKShareAPI._shareContent , __ZNKSt3__120__shared_ptr_pointerIPvPFvS1_ENS_9allocatorIvEEE13__get_deleterERKSt9type_info , __ZNSt3__120__shared_ptr_pointerIPvPFvS1_ENS_9allocatorIvEEE16__on_zero_sharedEv , __ZNSt3__120__shared_ptr_pointerIPvPFvS1_ENS_9allocatorIvEEED0Ev , __ZTVNSt3__120__shared_ptr_pointerIPvPFvS1_ENS_9allocatorIvEEEE , _CultureInfo_insert_into_shared_tables_mEF7A50DE94D03F4C663AEC7D7E23A0BD309F872C , __ZNSt3__120__shared_ptr_pointerIPvPFvS1_ENS_9allocatorIvEEED1Ev , _Renderer_set_sharedMaterial_mC94A354D9B0FCA081754A7CB51AEE5A9AD3946A3 , _MeshFilter_get_sharedMesh_mC076FD5461BFBBAD3BE49D25263CF140700D9902 , __Z46Register_UnityEngine_MeshFilter_get_sharedMeshv , _OBJC_IVAR_$_APMASIdentifierManager._sharedIdentifierManager , __Z51Register_UnityEngine_Rigidbody2D_get_sharedMaterialv , __Z50Register_UnityEngine_Collider2D_get_sharedMaterialv , _Renderer_get_sharedMaterial_m2BE9FF3D269968F2E323AC60EFBBCC0B26E7E6F9 , _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBSDKShareLinkContent._shareUUID , _CultureInfo_insert_into_shared_tables_mEF7A50DE94D03F4C663AEC7D7E23A0BD309F872C_MetadataUsageId , __Z50Register_UnityEngine_Collider2D_set_sharedMaterialv , _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBSDKMessageDialog._shareContent , __ZTSNSt3__120__shared_ptr_pointerIPvPFvS1_ENS_9allocatorIvEEEE , __ZNSt3__120__shared_ptr_pointerIPvPFvS1_ENS_9allocatorIvEEE21__on_zero_shared_weakEv , _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBSDKShareMessengerOpenGraphMusicTemplateContent._shareUUID , _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBSDKShareDialog._shareContent , _ACPUnityPlugin_shareUrl_m583D2391D75F884B54BB70EFAB6264B32077CBA4 , _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBUnityInterface._shareDialogMode , __Z55Register_UnityEngine_SkinnedMeshRenderer_set_sharedMeshv , _SharingIOS_share_mD5C0B1770361E9BF9A15E53FE83492A1CC592F54 , _Renderer_set_sharedMaterials_mC9C16BE3F6570586A26F9E91DEC403AF1AB69F51 , _SharingIOS_shareImageOnWhatsApp_mE011579CA7273B8251D9933D164AB1A79EA97D8F , __Z48Register_UnityEngine_Collider_get_sharedMaterialv , _SharingIOS_shareTextMessageOnWhatsApp_m860B374A0BF5F8ADFC66450EE9D70EC3746C2332 , __ZTINSt3__120__shared_ptr_pointerIPvPFvS1_ENS_9allocatorIvEEEE )
  "_shareTextMessageOnWhatsApp", referenced from:
      _SharingIOS_shareTextMessageOnWhatsApp_m860B374A0BF5F8ADFC66450EE9D70EC3746C2332 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _SharingIOS_ShowWhatsAppShareComposer_mB28E83CC9B377B6D1A78FC3E1C4EB211414DF954 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _SharingIOS_ShareTextMessageOnWhatsApp_mC14299D92BD29F96EA4C40EE010B10F5727F1D05 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _SharingIOS_shareTextMessageOnWhatsApp_m860B374A0BF5F8ADFC66450EE9D70EC3746C2332)
  "_webviewReload", referenced from:
      _WebViewNativeIOS_webviewReload_m8BB7262629619D96AAB6AF53BCAB4B3D7E2F0E97 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _WebViewNativeIOS_Reload_m4739848E253538424FFEC8C7FB8163E55D563336 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _WebViewNativeIOS_webviewReload_m8BB7262629619D96AAB6AF53BCAB4B3D7E2F0E97)
  "_isSocialShareServiceAvailable", referenced from:
      _SharingIOS_isSocialShareServiceAvailable_mB35077E44483B0583CBC47162F8226FD379CCC99 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _SharingIOS_IsFBShareServiceAvailable_m71089FAB74F009C4F97D140D37335EBFB341288A in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _SharingIOS_IsTwitterShareServiceAvailable_m3C5D56CC89707873308DEBA990F89EB5CECD8DBC in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _SharingIOS_isSocialShareServiceAvailable_mB35077E44483B0583CBC47162F8226FD379CCC99)
  "_sendMail", referenced from:
      _SharingIOS_sendMail_m6EF3E8C5BBEDF4081455AEAE7E06FD75DA12EBED in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _SharingIOS_sendMail_m6EF3E8C5BBEDF4081455AEAE7E06FD75DA12EBED)
  "_canSendMail", referenced from:
      _SharingIOS_canSendMail_m1218F0B9C137FA1FC3EEB80F1CC97EE8D6D53723 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _SharingIOS_IsMailServiceAvailable_mB4206F52842E24241B5735252066050F605F71CA in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _SharingIOS_canSendMail_m1218F0B9C137FA1FC3EEB80F1CC97EE8D6D53723)
  "_canShareOnWhatsApp", referenced from:
      _SharingIOS_canShareOnWhatsApp_m5FE5DA950CB484CA1AA29273BED8726097D678CA in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _SharingIOS_IsWhatsAppServiceAvailable_mC120CA63B9EE43E527A409C643C37611E837B9D5 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _SharingIOS_canShareOnWhatsApp_m5FE5DA950CB484CA1AA29273BED8726097D678CA)
  "_cpnpNetworkConnectivitySetHostAddress", referenced from:
      _NetworkConnectivityIOS_cpnpNetworkConnectivitySetHostAddress_m2ED3F9A74E55336039E004070F09CA7ED8B1EA13 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _NetworkConnectivityIOS_Initialise_mD28361CE98D6B1DCC52B552FCFFF9A48810C97CB in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _NetworkConnectivityIOS_cpnpNetworkConnectivitySetHostAddress_m2ED3F9A74E55336039E004070F09CA7ED8B1EA13)
  "_setAllowsImageEditing", referenced from:
      _MediaLibraryIOS_setAllowsImageEditing_m925F1416EBEC5C3292DA723F1AF54439F1E486F6 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _MediaLibraryIOS_Awake_m48EBBAEA83E8013B3BD1AB5D877A6F8B61C563F3 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _MediaLibraryIOS_SetAllowsImageEditing_m8F2626C3C49BBB09AF2FB90CE460DE353DFDA07B in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _MediaLibraryIOS_setAllowsImageEditing_m925F1416EBEC5C3292DA723F1AF54439F1E486F6)
  "_authenticatePlayer", referenced from:
      _iOSLocalUser_authenticatePlayer_m0BAA228DCD538967D30A58178B1325EC8350470B in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _iOSLocalUser_Authenticate_m7F53F4A27AE664427BBA67B119C0BB2305EFF9D6 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _iOSLocalUser_authenticatePlayer_m0BAA228DCD538967D30A58178B1325EC8350470B)
  "_loadScores", referenced from:
      _iOSLeaderboard_loadScores_m632B51FCFD9BF2B30F4580700E0249EE58152F13 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _iOSLeaderboard_LoadScores_mEF1B86AB4ED424D349376FA52D02742A5E84E65C in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _iOSLeaderboard_loadScores_m632B51FCFD9BF2B30F4580700E0249EE58152F13)
  "_loadAchievementImage", referenced from:
      _iOSAchievementDescription_loadAchievementImage_m6DF8017471EF6417DBF45BB602AB30EE2C7C6D9E in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _iOSAchievementDescription_RequestForImage_m149593809842F6855345753F87792A9A11EBF9C5 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _iOSAchievementDescription_loadAchievementImage_m6DF8017471EF6417DBF45BB602AB30EE2C7C6D9E)
  "_webviewSetBackgroundColor", referenced from:
      _WebViewNativeIOS_webviewSetBackgroundColor_mDFC330AFEEE8AE8AF69205C116239E8F211EA368 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _WebViewNativeIOS_SetBackgroundColor_mF45B1AFFD4CA4D7F7A598EA31FA7668DCFBCBCCA in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _WebViewNativeIOS_webviewSetBackgroundColor_mDFC330AFEEE8AE8AF69205C116239E8F211EA368)
  "_GoogleSignIn_Configure", referenced from:
      _GoogleSignInImpl_GoogleSignIn_Configure_mB5B5EA5B5E0EFCEEF15B998608542DC578B2F223 in Assembly-CSharp2.o
     (maybe you meant: _GoogleSignInImpl_GoogleSignIn_Configure_mB5B5EA5B5E0EFCEEF15B998608542DC578B2F223)
  "_reportProgress", referenced from:
      _iOSAchievement_reportProgress_m4D9E695FCB0A9AB23AAF89E17452DBB27CFEECA5 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _iOSAchievement_ReportProgress_mD156915D3CF6DD071EE26729CF038D7F32F3207C in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _iOSAchievement_reportProgress_m4D9E695FCB0A9AB23AAF89E17452DBB27CFEECA5)
  "_cpnpCloudServicesRemoveKey", referenced from:
      _CloudServicesIOS_cpnpCloudServicesRemoveKey_m2CEEC1C05DA618F8B1B6374EB7F76FE5D70FAD37 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
      _CloudServicesIOS_RemoveKey_m284149F3767AB2ECE0CC9AE79E6D769A2F6262BE in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
     (maybe you meant: _CloudServicesIOS_cpnpCloudServicesRemoveKey_m2CEEC1C05DA618F8B1B6374EB7F76FE5D70FAD37)
  "_loadPhoto", referenced from:
      _iOSUser_loadPhoto_m7CEBB055D44793BC9F05EDF0D1C8FB265B761A0E in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _iOSUser_RequestForImage_m87D0F00E86E1DD1F6F57187853A7F25C6BB13268 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _iOSUser_loadPhoto_m7CEBB055D44793BC9F05EDF0D1C8FB265B761A0E)
  "_webviewClearCache", referenced from:
      _WebViewNativeIOS_webviewClearCache_mF5960687D15ED195EF2E702BA668E299F953A6B5 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _WebViewNativeIOS_ClearCache_mC260CDD452CEAB24EE818D4463DEB1A9AA44D9C6 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _WebViewNativeIOS_webviewClearCache_mF5960687D15ED195EF2E702BA668E299F953A6B5)
  "_cpnpCloudServicesGetDouble", referenced from:
      _CloudServicesIOS_cpnpCloudServicesGetDouble_mB885CC60007919315905F4317DABD7840CEF2FD1 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
      _CloudServicesIOS_GetDouble_m8784E1F264751D446CA489A7831CA7DDDBD6BAC3 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
     (maybe you meant: _CloudServicesIOS_cpnpCloudServicesGetDouble_mB885CC60007919315905F4317DABD7840CEF2FD1)
  "_webviewSetNormalisedFrame", referenced from:
      _WebViewNativeIOS_webviewSetNormalisedFrame_m9E7D9EF5EA7A58B0CB22FF6E3CFD40825B907104 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _WebViewNativeIOS_SetFrame_mA68F2B8C871F32965245B8E8A3C4A420CAD9F7DE in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _WebViewNativeIOS_webviewSetNormalisedFrame_m9E7D9EF5EA7A58B0CB22FF6E3CFD40825B907104)
  "_webviewSetShowSpinnerOnLoad", referenced from:
      _WebViewNativeIOS_webviewSetShowSpinnerOnLoad_m8CA5916A42E9047932F0C60644B7DFB9E4A85016 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _WebViewNativeIOS_SetShowSpinnerOnLoad_mED264E21BA4F25C6C8CBF20A5E94CFC9F32403B8 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _WebViewNativeIOS_webviewSetShowSpinnerOnLoad_m8CA5916A42E9047932F0C60644B7DFB9E4A85016)
  "_saveImageToGallery", referenced from:
      _MediaLibraryIOS_saveImageToGallery_mD7367452F54E9C6D16199C1D48A5CE6FBEB224C7 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _MediaLibraryIOS_SaveImageToGallery_mF7BBD44B6562E524857B10EDC2CEFB6473BB92DE in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _MediaLibraryIOS_saveImageToGallery_mD7367452F54E9C6D16199C1D48A5CE6FBEB224C7)
  "_webviewSetCanHide", referenced from:
      _WebViewNativeIOS_webviewSetCanHide_m0CF3522C064E9EE4F4F19B8653C4B55696099552 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _WebViewNativeIOS_SetCanHide_mAA46659C4E3926C9AB413CDB9D957256793AAE4E in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _WebViewNativeIOS_webviewSetCanHide_m0CF3522C064E9EE4F4F19B8653C4B55696099552)
  "_setPopoverPoint", referenced from:
      _UIIOS_setPopoverPoint_m1E7B64116B7F8172528557CAEA0A23EDBCE135B1 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass3.o
      _UIIOS_SetPopoverPoint_m1615EEF40C99914C4585602266676B8997046A82 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass3.o
     (maybe you meant: _UIIOS_setPopoverPoint_m1E7B64116B7F8172528557CAEA0A23EDBCE135B1)
  "_showLeaderboardView", referenced from:
      _GameServicesIOS_showLeaderboardView_mEC26FF24FC0F4BECD31EC47FFEBE9A2C9A453F3A in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
      _GameServicesIOS_ShowLeaderboardUIWithID_mB3CE0295ED0C435C2626089EA9B0F1F9BC27CFDB in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
     (maybe you meant: _GameServicesIOS_showLeaderboardView_mEC26FF24FC0F4BECD31EC47FFEBE9A2C9A453F3A)
  "_webviewShow", referenced from:
      _WebViewNativeIOS_webviewShow_m93E8F66BD2E2E1C9BA9B6D87A234AF45A5DD2BBD in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _WebViewNativeIOS_Show_m303FB25D53E67399C4D615119D5760DBCD8C1855 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _WebViewNativeIOS_webviewShow_m93E8F66BD2E2E1C9BA9B6D87A234AF45A5DD2BBD)
  "_cpnpCloudServicesSetString", referenced from:
      _CloudServicesIOS_cpnpCloudServicesSetString_mC408EB88AFFCCBAE9C06588172E8E61E6D0D0688 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
     (maybe you meant: _CloudServicesIOS_cpnpCloudServicesSetString_mC408EB88AFFCCBAE9C06588172E8E61E6D0D0688)
  "_cpnpCloudServicesInitialise", referenced from:
      _CloudServicesIOS_cpnpCloudServicesInitialise_m3E8F8AFC35CE4304CE5C8BDB8CBE2E64BAB1DABB in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
      _CloudServicesIOS_Initialise_m2141F3E26E8D915EF0897872C97B34124BF71236 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
     (maybe you meant: _CloudServicesIOS_cpnpCloudServicesInitialise_m3E8F8AFC35CE4304CE5C8BDB8CBE2E64BAB1DABB)
  "_GoogleSignIn_EnableDebugLogging", referenced from:
      _GoogleSignInImpl_EnableDebugLogging_m4E89F1AC509DD04B32E1C21378858229190EFEE3 in Assembly-CSharp2.o
      _GoogleSignInImpl_GoogleSignIn_EnableDebugLogging_m07AC19E9A373398D51ED80C3ACF5D3766FEE9F39 in Assembly-CSharp2.o
     (maybe you meant: _GoogleSignInImpl_GoogleSignIn_EnableDebugLogging_m07AC19E9A373398D51ED80C3ACF5D3766FEE9F39, _GoogleSignIn_EnableDebugLogging_m9D0E15290DC3E4D436EAB5C72CCFE4B6FE339393_MetadataUsageId , _GoogleSignIn_EnableDebugLogging_m9D0E15290DC3E4D436EAB5C72CCFE4B6FE339393 )
  "_cpnpCloudServicesGetString", referenced from:
      _CloudServicesIOS_cpnpCloudServicesGetString_m352EA3641E13E028E236630B78C0F403BF746B14 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
     (maybe you meant: _CloudServicesIOS_cpnpCloudServicesGetString_m352EA3641E13E028E236630B78C0F403BF746B14)
  "_sendTextMessage", referenced from:
      _SharingIOS_sendTextMessage_mF141D4719B74776CA62489CAC7478B55197266BA in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _SharingIOS_sendTextMessage_mF141D4719B74776CA62489CAC7478B55197266BA)
  "_webviewCreate", referenced from:
      _WebViewNativeIOS_webviewCreate_m15F6FE189982135E7A49BFB1C7755CFEFC4DF5D1 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _WebViewNativeIOS_Create_m737017EF0FA35B49D00AE7B113A567DD350B6F4D in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _WebViewNativeIOS_webviewCreate_m15F6FE189982135E7A49BFB1C7755CFEFC4DF5D1)
  "_isMessagingAvailable", referenced from:
      _SharingIOS_isMessagingAvailable_mA0083E578334971970629C05B79DAE7D48548D62 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _SharingIOS_IsMessagingServiceAvailable_m16DB93654718EA4C55F86C10F6ED50516F5790C3 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _SharingIOS_isMessagingAvailable_mA0083E578334971970629C05B79DAE7D48548D62)
  "_enabledNotificationTypes", referenced from:
      _NotificationServiceIOS_enabledNotificationTypes_m170D69125CB4620847D10018289A9864C03A28AA in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
      _NotificationServiceIOS_EnabledNotificationTypes_m6CF9C0BA3DC080B21D7541088BE9D349BB11EEA5 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
     (maybe you meant: __Z74Register_UnityEngine_iOS_NotificationServices_get_enabledNotificationTypesv, _NotificationServiceIOS_enabledNotificationTypes_m170D69125CB4620847D10018289A9864C03A28AA )
  "_unregisterForRemoteNotifications", referenced from:
      _NotificationServiceIOS_unregisterForRemoteNotifications_mFCC5A3531A703F7291EC531620E49C008FB63269 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
      _NotificationServiceIOS_UnregisterForRemoteNotifications_mAE55323ECD93B97372824B3159D9254791822E1A in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
     (maybe you meant: _NotificationServiceIOS_unregisterForRemoteNotifications_mFCC5A3531A703F7291EC531620E49C008FB63269)
  "_registerNotificationTypes", referenced from:
      _NotificationServiceIOS_registerNotificationTypes_m872F8DF46513265AD73D6F19897618BD40AD7CF7 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
      _NotificationServiceIOS_RegisterNotificationTypes_m71A54C7760A5E534A723A15AC0EB8B0EE9FA8421 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
     (maybe you meant: _GameServicesIOS_showDefaultAchievementCompletionBanner_m6B151BE210BCC82EA2E1BF99E73FC242BD0109D3 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
      _GameServicesIOS_Awake_m14CC752E2463F0C2FB09D1465ADBF3CF0981B3CC in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
      _GameServicesIOS_ShowDefaultAchievementCompletionBanner_m2B9AAC87DD8BB0AFF3967BB77A4DEC9105188F1B in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
     (maybe you meant: _GameServicesIOS_showDefaultAchievementCompletionBanner_m6B151BE210BCC82EA2E1BF99E73FC242BD0109D3)
  "_pickImage", referenced from:
      _MediaLibraryIOS_pickImage_m797DDEB9CAB0B8FF431FE843CA67F8A7AC069CBF in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _MediaLibraryIOS_PickImage_m4949CD996B53F54DB32818D8938F75461A28B2E9 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _MediaLibraryIOS_pickImage_m797DDEB9CAB0B8FF431FE843CA67F8A7AC069CBF)
  "_loadPlayers", referenced from:
      _GameServicesIOS_loadPlayers_mA0DCF3157FDE8742E909791CE0747AB1F84BA310 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
      _GameServicesIOS_LoadUsers_m8796AD25227BAA4F73B8EC29FDC319EDF3CD5D98 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
     (maybe you meant: _GameServicesIOS_loadPlayers_mA0DCF3157FDE8742E909791CE0747AB1F84BA310)
  "_webviewSetControlType", referenced from:
      _WebViewNativeIOS_webviewSetControlType_mAAC1B923FBA499137F99C9058BEBF482656213ED in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _WebViewNativeIOS_SetControlType_m5425CEAD5B0B98B32475D97EDD277827EEB41203 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _WebViewNativeIOS_webviewSetControlType_mAAC1B923FBA499137F99C9058BEBF482656213ED)
  "_readContacts", referenced from:
      _AddressBookIOS_readContacts_mCC445CCC7F55E5772724E571F4B005908A04181C in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
      _AddressBookIOS_ReadContacts_m0BD41B7471EF362D1260C8860B870241A29A774F in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
     (maybe you meant: _AddressBookIOS_readContacts_mCC445CCC7F55E5772724E571F4B005908A04181C)
  "_webviewLoadData", referenced from:
      _WebViewNativeIOS_webviewLoadData_m1BA7C5C429CCFEB5ECBE56A09BF293F0092AC738 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _WebViewNativeIOS_webviewLoadData_m1BA7C5C429CCFEB5ECBE56A09BF293F0092AC738)
  "_playVideoFromURL", referenced from:
      _MediaLibraryIOS_playVideoFromURL_mC465ECE9AB6E4A3DF504DDBDA926606FCBE84A4B in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _MediaLibraryIOS_PlayVideoFromURL_m78BDF414F4B7888FA6B218322FBF0C47E540A0E7 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _MediaLibraryIOS_playVideoFromURL_mC465ECE9AB6E4A3DF504DDBDA926606FCBE84A4B)
  "_GoogleSignIn_GetEmail", referenced from:
      _GoogleSignInImpl_GoogleSignIn_GetEmail_m7525245614B8CA692FF3619084CA531D0A0F6C74 in Assembly-CSharp2.o
      _U3CU3Ec__DisplayClass5_0_U3Cget_ResultU3Eb__1_mD2E987E43D1A86D08E25CE8E1C3FB8C0D9D87511 in Assembly-CSharp2.o
     (maybe you meant: _GoogleSignInImpl_GoogleSignIn_GetEmail_m7525245614B8CA692FF3619084CA531D0A0F6C74)
  "_GoogleSignIn_Disconnect", referenced from:
      _GoogleSignInImpl_Disconnect_m0B6427190751D8174A3B77F3BC07196367E61143 in Assembly-CSharp2.o
      _GoogleSignInImpl_GoogleSignIn_Disconnect_m2CFCE09C8555491F0058215FCE13B13DB7FDFD4B in Assembly-CSharp2.o
     (maybe you meant: 
      _NotificationServiceIOS_CancelAllLocalNotification_mB16D125F63BFA629A1B653A3DE1E130EBAC7E608 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass1.o
     (maybe you meant: _NotificationServiceIOS_cancelAllLocalNotifications_mD9032EF8C59A4E5E54D3302EA6B7C2DA01AA6C39)
  "_cpnpCloudServicesGetDictionary", referenced from:
      _CloudServicesIOS_cpnpCloudServicesGetDictionary_m33D54EE2782FFE0181E2EBA3D1990FE06622885A 
      _iOSScore_ReportScore_m88DDFEAC9A3684FF8F7DEBD600670E7E4CEC754D in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _iOSScore_reportScore_m15181752B1C360BAA8748328DA3C24F0A33145A7)
  "_webviewLoadRequest", referenced from:
      _WebViewNativeIOS_webviewLoadRequest_m57F31D18A140E3AD663C61AF763C7C637F59A1F1 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _WebViewNativeIOS_webviewLoadRequest_m57F31D18A140E3AD663C61AF763C7C637F59A1F1)
  "_playVideoFromGallery", referenced from:
      _MediaLibraryIOS_playVideoFromGallery_m22B681338554E8177DE9850FC3C95A8D9D9FE1DF in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _MediaLibraryIOS_PlayVideoFromGallery_m038D39F94A51F847EF5A315E84272DFD70F31207 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _MediaLibraryIOS_playVideoFromGallery_m22B681338554E8177DE9850FC3C95A8D9D9FE1DF)
  "_webviewHide", referenced from:
      _WebViewNativeIOS_webviewHide_m576C969BEFAFF5C168DC55990B6F43F75BCD6D2A in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _WebViewNativeIOS_Hide_mEEBBC4AF20FCFEC6637A1002A56FD142B2B683EB in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _WebViewNativeIOS_webviewHide_m576C969BEFAFF5C168DC55990B6F43F75BCD6D2A)
  "_playVideoUsingWebView", referenced from:
      _MediaLibraryIOS_playVideoUsingWebView_mAC95C4A6C0651258C7DE10DC3105DF6745627D98 in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
      _MediaLibraryIOS_PlayEmbeddedVideo_m82082E34B744CB5F787972187856BD7232B3DE2A in Assembly-CSharp-firstpass2.o
     (maybe you meant: _MediaLibraryIOS_playVideoUsingWebView_mAC95C4A6C0651258C7DE10DC3105DF6745627D98)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: please give us some context, what did you try to achieve, when did it happen?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like You have added Google Sign in SDK in Your Project, but didn't add GoogleSingIn libs files for iOS.

And it looks like your project misses GoogleSignIn.h , GoogleSingIn.mm and probably GoogleSignInAppController.h and GoogleSignInAppController.mm.

Try to check your SDK package one more time , these files should be there. If so, just add them to Assets/YOUR_PATH_TO_GOOGLE_SING_IN_ASSETS/, by default is Assets/Plugins/iOS/GoogleSignIn

Comment: Really thank you very much friend, I do not have much knowledge of unity, because I focus more on ios, and I really hardly find the error, if not for your answer, I would not have been able to solve it, really thank you very much

Comment: I also would have never found a solution without this answer, thank you!